# In SourceMod, how do I check if a plugin exists?

Tags: scripting, game-development, steam

In SourceMod, how do I check if a plugin exists? I tried the `GetFeatureStatus` method, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If a plugin has registered itself as a Library, you can check if it exists using the `LibraryExists` command on the name it registered.  Traditionally, this name is in all lowercase, but some plugins/extensions use mixed-case, such as SteamTools (which uses "SteamTools").

Having said that, it's generally better to cache whether a library exists instead of constantly calling this command... but then a library can be unloaded or loaded on your without your knowledge.  There are functions to catch that.

So, the best way is generally to do something like this (using the [NativeVotes](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=208008) plugin as an example).

```
#undef REQUIRE_PLUGIN
#include <nativevotes>

//global variable
new bool:g_bNativeVotes = false;

public OnAllPluginsLoaded()
{
    g_bNativeVotes = LibraryExists("nativevotes");
}

public OnLibraryAdded(const String:name[])
{
    if (StrEqual(name, "nativevotes"))
    {
        g_bNativeVotes = true;
    }
}

public OnLibraryRemoved(const String:name[])
{
    if (StrEqual(name, "nativevotes"))
    {
        g_bNativeVotes = false;
    }
}
```

If a plugin isn't registered as a library, you can use GetFeatureStatus to check for a particular native.  The catch is in realizing that this function doesn't return a bool, but rather a `FeatureStatus_` value.

For instance, here's how I'd check for a (in development) feature for the same plugin as mentioned above:

```
if (GetFeatureStatus(FeatureType_Native, "NativeVotes_IsVoteCommandRegistered") == FeatureStatus_Available)
{
    // Do something with vote commands.
}
```